# How can I move the legend position with grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, gridextra

I´m trying to arrange 4 plots in a page, placing the legend in the bottom center

I used this to get the legends from one of the plots (as they will be the same for the four plots)

```
    get_legend<-function(myggplot){
    tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(myggplot))
    leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
    legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
    return(legend)
    }
```

then, I get the legend from any of the plots

```
   legend <- get_legend(p2)
```

so for the figure I used:

```
 tt <-grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p6, p7, p8, p9, legend,
                          nrow = 2, #
                          left = textGrob("Mammalian species richness", rot = 90, vjust = 1, 
                                          gp = gpar(fontsize = 12))))
```

but what I´ve got is this:

[image]

How can I move the legend to the center button and have 2rows 2 columns?
commands `nrow`, `ncol` did not work as I  received an error message, neither something like

```
tt  <- tt + theme(legend.position ="bottom").
```

ps. just in case this info is important, if I attempt not to place any legend I could have the four plots in a grid as I want, but without legends, so, you understand is not good for publication.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the argument `layout_matrix` in `grid.arrange` for more control.

A reproducible example,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

get_legend<-function(myggplot){
    tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(myggplot))
    leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
    legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
    return(legend)
    }

p <- ggplot()
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, col=factor(am))) + geom_point()
legend <- get_legend(p2)


grid.arrange(p, p, p, p, legend, 
             layout_matrix=rbind(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,5)))
```

Which produces

[image]

Or perhaps you want

```
grid.arrange(p, p ,p, p, legend, 
             layout_matrix=rbind(c(1,1,2,2,5), c(3,3,4,4,5)))
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks for your response user20650, despite the fact that this is not a proper question. It worked, I also used layout_matrix=rbind(c(1,2), c(3,4), c(5,5))) to place it at the button. However, to the right is better because in the button there are much space and legend still in two rows, and don´t know how to make it flat...thanks!!

Comment: to make it flat , position the legend at the bottom of the original ggplot: ie `p2 = p2 + theme(legend.position="bottom")` , then continue as before.

Comment: Thanks much, it worked. However, I´ve been trying to delete the space between the legend and the plots, but without luck. Could you please give me some insight in how can I do this. The plots shrank after placing the legend at the button (horizontally or vertically), because of this space. This does not happen with the right position.

Comment: @lep ; you can probably do this by adding in extra elements in to the layout_matrix as I did in the second example (see the duplicate values of of 1 to 4 to increase the width of these plots. However, this may be easier `grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p,p,p,p, nrow=2), legend, ncol=1, heights=c(9,1))`

Comment: After flattening the legend, you should add a theme to plot to remove legend like `p = p + theme(legend.position = 'none')`.

Answer (score 0):

To complement `user20650`'s answer and to answer the OP completely, I have plotted the same plot four times but I addressed the question.

To be able to use the following code, you need to have `cowplot` and `ggpubr` package installed for `gridExtra` formatting.

Although the OP has a function to get the legend information, I encountered some issues with it so I had to use `cowplot`.

For `layout_matrix` format, please refer to [this page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html).

```
library(cowplot)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggpubr)



p =  ggplot2::ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, col = factor(am))) + 
  ggplot2::geom_point() + 
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Car Type", labels=c("fast", "slow"), ) +
  labs(x = '', y = '') +
  ggtitle('Car')  +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 8, hjust = 0.5),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 1), 
        legend.position = 'top')
legend = cowplot::get_legend(p)

p = p + ggplot2::theme(legend.position = 'none')

gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = list(p, p, p, p, legend),
                        left = ggpubr::text_grob("Width", 
                                                 rot = 90, 
                                                 vjust = 1),
                        bottom = ggpubr::text_grob("Mile Per Gallon", 
                                                   rot = 0, 
                                                   vjust = 0),
                        
                        layout_matrix = rbind(c(5, 5), 
                                              c(1, 2), 
                                              c(1, 2),
                                              c(1, 2), 
                                              c(1, 2),
                                              c(1, 2), 
                                              c(1, 2),
                                              c(1, 2),
                                              c(3, 4),
                                              c(3, 4),
                                              c(3, 4),
                                              c(3, 4),
                                              c(3, 4),
                                              c(3, 4),
                                              c(3, 4)))
```

[image]

Comment: but no need for ggpubr; def easier just to use the `grid` package with `grid::textGrob`